# C# '(class) var' - what IS this construction

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn some C#, one of the code snippets I found used:

```
(CheckBox)c
```

(Where c was the result of foreach)

I get that it's doing this so that the compiler knows that c will behave as a checkbox, my question is: what is this type of construction called? I'd like to be able to google to understand it better.

Thanks!

Comment: It's called a [`cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) <-- Clicky

Comment: @JesonPark What more could you want? The question is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a *cast*. As you say, it's used here to tell the compiler that `c` is in fact a checkbox. There is also a [longer article on casting on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). In case of `foreach` with a non-generic `IEnumerable`, which I think is what you're doing, there are also two ways to avoid this cast in the loop body:

```
for (CheckBox c in xs) {
}

for (var c in xs.Cast<CheckBox>()) {
}
```

Both pieces of code expose `c` as a `CheckBox` now, eliminating the need for a cast. I'd probably use the first one, as it's the most idiomatic (as well as the approach familiar from .NET 1.1 and Java).

Answer (score 2):

It casts the c variable to type CheckBox. I think in your example it is a object the variable c, and if you then convert it to CheckBox, you get access to all the properties like "IsChecked" "Name" etc

In other words.

before the cast:

```
bool isItChecked = c.IsChecked; // this would not compile because object does not have a property "IsChecked"
```

So to get this working we must tell the compiler that the variable c is of type CheckBox like this:

```
var checkBoxC = (CheckBox)c; // The Cast
bool isItChecked = checkBoxC.IsChecked; // access the casted items properties.
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447634/A-Beginners-Tutorial-Type-Casting-and-Type-Convers) is a good beginners tutorial on typecasting, you should check "Explicit casts" because that is what you are doing.

PS: This is needed because c# is [strongly typed and not weakly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing).

Answer (score 1):

It is called "Casting".
Check out for more information:

> [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That we call `casting`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). Some tutorials: [one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/cast) and [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447634/A-Beginners-Tutorial-Type-Casting-and-Type-Convers)

You also have something related that is called `boxing and unboxing`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

What your example does is letting you know that the `object c` is actually a `checkbox`. That way you can access all the properties of a `checkbox`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called casting. You do this when you *know* that the type of 'c' will be Checkbox when the code executes. However, it is possible that c is not a Checkbox, in which case you will get an [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx).

In truth, C# provides many constructs to avoid casting, like [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and [Generic Type Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

As a rule of thumb: only use casting when you really cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "[Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion)" or "[UnBoxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)"

```
static private void TestBoxingAndUnboxing()
{
 int i = 123;
 object o = i; // Implicit boxing
 i = 456; // Change the contents of i
 int j = (int)o; // Unboxing (may throw an exception if the types are incompatible)
}

//this function is about 2*Log(N) faster
static private void TestNoBoxingAndUnboxing()
{
 int i = 123;
 i = 456; // Change the contents of i
 int j = i; // Compatible types
}
```

Understand the difference between two, although they are doing the same thing.

Comment: For completeness: implicit casting is also called coercion. This is done at compile time as well in contrast to casting.

Comment: As also mentioned by @Loetn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22831734/3331861), c was boxed into object type which was unboxed later to checkbox